# .NET Core 3.1 Ubuntu 503 service unavailable / AH01114 failed to make connection to backend (port 5000)

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-18.04, .net-core-3.1

I created a .NET Core 3.1 application on a Windows box using Visual Studio. I deployed it to an Ubuntu 18.04 server using basic file copy commands. All is well and the app works great.

I then published the application on the Ubuntu box itself (CI project using Bamboo). The application does not respond (gives a 503 service unavailable).   The log file complains of an AH01114: HTTP: failed to make a connection to backend: 127.0.0.1.

After some research, I ran `net stat --tcp --listen --numeric ports` with the Visual Studio build version and the Ubuntu `dotnet publish` version. The results showed that `localhost:5000` was being listened to using the Visual Studio (working) built version.

```
daniel@ubuntu-sandbox:~$ netstat --tcp --listen --numeric-ports
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:80                 [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:22                 [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:5000      [::]:*                  LISTEN     

daniel@ubuntu-sandbox:~$ netstat --tcp --listen --numeric-ports
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:80                 [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:22                 [::]:*                  LISTEN     
daniel@ubuntu-sandbox:~$
```

I looked at my (vanilla) netcore.conf file for Apache:

```
daniel@ubuntu-sandbox:~$ cat /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/netcore.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>  
   ServerName www.DOMAIN.COM  
   ProxyPreserveHost On  
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/  
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/  
   RewriteEngine on  
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]  
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]  
   RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:5000/$1 [P]  
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/netcore-error.log  
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/netcore-access.log common  
</VirtualHost>
```

And sure enough, there's the 5000.

How do I get this resolved? Am I missing a certificate? Is Visual Studio embedding a developer one in its build that I don't have when I build it on the Ubuntu box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this particular problem out.  For those who follow with a similar problem, here's what I did.

tl;dr; answer:

Update the file permissions on the files post compilation:

```
sudo chmod 664 -R /var/netcore/* && sudo chmod 771 /var/netcore
```

More detailed explainer on what I did to diagnose this:

```
sudo journalctl -fu YOUR_DOTNET_CORE_APPNAME_HERE.service
```

This showed me that access was denied on my dll.   I compared the permissions on these files to those that the Visual Studio build made, matched them up, restarted the service and it worked.